# Getting mod_wsgi to work with Python 2.7/Apache on Windows Server 2012; cannot load module

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, windows-server-2008-r2

I successfully installed mod_wsgi via `pip install mod_wsgi` on Windows. However, when I copy the output of `mod_wsgi-express module-config` into my httpd.conf and try to start the httpd, I get the following error:

`httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 185 of C:/path/to/httpd.conf: Cannot load c:/path/to/venv/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.pyd into server`

This is already after correcting the pasted output of `module-config`, as it was `.../venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgiNone` (note the "None"). I changed the "None" to ".pyd" as this is the correct path.

I already tried to install it outside the virtual env (Python being at C:\Python27), but it didn't make a difference -> same error.

I also tried to uninstall/re-install mod_wsgi. I had one failed install as Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 (Version 9.0.0.30729) was not present. After that installation, the mod_wsgi always installed OK.

The apache (Apache/2.4.27 (Win32)) comes from the xampp package and starts without issues when I remove the added lines for wsgi.

I need to use Python 2.7 because of a third-party module. So going for 3.x is unfortunately not an option at the moment.

Exact Python version is 2.7.13 (32-bit).

For completeness, the output of `module-config` is:

`LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/www/my_project/venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgiNone"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/www/my_project/venv"`

**Update:** tried one more thing:

- Uninstalled mod_wsgi (with pip)
- `set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:/WWW/apache"`
- And `pip install mod_wsgi` again

Still the same error...

Comment: I keep hearing that 32 bit Python is causing issues. Not sure if this relates to Python, or whether because some people are mixing architectures and using 64 bit versions of the compiler or Apache. If you are going to use 32 bit Python, the Apache and the compiler must also be 32 bit. Also, the Python installation must be installed for all users, not just yourself.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the Apache was built with VC14, but Python 2.7 naturally with VC9. Installing an Apache built with VC9 solved my issue.

Comment: Yep. It is hit and miss as to whether mixing VC9 and VC14 works. It does for some people but not for others. Where did you get your Apache built with VC9? Finding a recent Apache version for VC9 is getting much more difficult.

Comment: Didn't do the install but sys admin went with an older 2.4.x. from an xampp package. However, I found recent VC9 versions here: https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx